# Django Render function: template not printing variable

Tags: python, django

I go to `accounts/login` and am prompted with a login page. When I type in a username and password, it takes me to profile.html. From there I just see the word profile, but I want it to also show {{ user.username }}. The DOM just has `<p></p>` empty.

I have turned on debugging PDB, but no traceback or anything occurs.

LoginView.py

```
def login_view(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username', '')
    password = request.POST.get('password', '')
    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            print(user)
            print(user.username)
            return render(request, '/', {
                'username': username,
                'user': user
            })
            # return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        return 'Please enter your UN and PW'
```

profile.html

```
 {% block content %}
<html>
<head>
    <title>PROFILE</title>
</head>
<body>
    PROFILE
</body>
<p>
    {{ user.username }}
</p>
</html>
{% endblock %}
```

If somebody could give me debugging tips, manual references, or an explanation of why user.username is not appearing, I will be grateful. Cheers

**UPDATE IMPORTANT INFO:**

So I think the problem resides with the user variable and not some silly mistake on my part regarding the method. If I use

```
return render(request, '/', {
    'Kitty': 5,     
})
```

and then on the form I user `{{ Kitty }}` sure enough it does print 5. But you probably knew that already.

**UPDATE 2** Inside my settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)
```

and

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**UPDATE 3**

```
def login_view(request):
    myUserName = request.POST.get('username', '')
    password = request.POST.get('password', '')
    user = auth.authenticate(username=myUserName, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            print(user)
            print(user.username)
            return render(request, '/', {
                'Kitty': 5,
                'myUserName': myUserName,     
            })
            # return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        return 'Please enter your UN and PW'

<p>
    {{ user.get_username }}
</p>
<p>
    {{ Kitty }}
</p>
<p>
    {{ myUserName }}
</p>
```

^^^ Suggestion to rename UserName

**UPDATE 5** This is probably the best I can manage with debugging

```
DEBUG (0.002) QUERY = 'SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."password", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."is_superu
ser", "auth_user"."username", "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_user"."is_st
aff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user" WHERE "auth_user"."username" = %s' - PARAMS =
('heebeans',); args=('heebeans',)
```

By the way, heebeans is a user with UN "heebeans" and PW "heebeans"

Thanks for all your support thus far!

Comment: This may be an issue of variable names. In django, `user` is an object. I suspect that since you try to render `user` and `username`, it may be trying to access the `username` (your variable) of `user` (the django object). Since that doesn't exist, it passes the silent error. Try renaming `username` to perhaps `user_name` and put that variable in the template and let me know what happens.

Comment: What is the value of `myUserName` if you print it in your view?

Comment: I'm really sorry for being incompetent, but how do I print it from my view? Is there easy way to have it show up in the command shell? Still not sure how to debug stuff properly

Comment: If you're in the development environment, you can just do as you did above with `print(variable_name)` and check the terminal output on the one your server is running on. If you're in a production environment, it'll be in the access or error logs somewhere.

Comment: @MatthewR. as of late somehow I got the shell to throw up some data. According to the query django is trying to find the user "heebeans" but I'm not sure

Comment: I was looking more for the value of the `myUserName` variable from your `LoginView.py`, because I'm sure your database has a correct user record. Are you able to view the value of the variable in your view at all?

Comment: @MatthewR. yeah I'm really unsure on how to do that I've been looking around print won't work for some reason so I used `print >>sys.stderr, myUserName` and `{% debug %}`. I know you're doing your best to help and I'm thankful. It's just somehow something is lost when rendering the template.

Comment: This is slightly hacky, but if `DEBUG = True` in your `settings.py`, try throwing an error in your template (like an `{% if something %}` without an `{% endif %}`) to invoke the error page. That should tell you what the value of all of your variables are once they are passed to the response handler. From there, try checking the what the value of `myUserName` is, whether the template is being passed those variables for rendering (usually in the Traceback directly underneath your view function), and look around for other possible issues.

Comment: @MatthewR. I think I figured out what went wrong. It's not going to be pretty because it was in a part of the code not visible on this post. I'll dig into it and update, but as for right now thanks for the advice I'll get back.

Comment: The issue turned out to be a really dumb mistake on my part. LoginView.py wasn't even being called, instead a different view function was doing the rendering. There was no way you guys could have known that as I didn't post the whole thing and I really do sincerely apologize. I'm sorry for wasting your time, the problem was resolved from another part

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to pass a username object as context to your view. By default, [Django includes that for its template context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#context-processors). The User object is stored in a variable called "user". You can use the User object's [get_username()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.get_username) method. Sample code below:

LoginView.py

```
def login_view(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username', '')
    password = request.POST.get('password', '')
    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            print(user)
            print(user.username)
            return render(request, '/')
            # return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        return 'Please enter your UN and PW'
```

profile.html

```
{% block content %}
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PROFILE</title>
    </head>
<body>
    PROFILE
</body>
<p>
    {{ user.get_username }}
</p>
</html>
{% endblock %}
```

Make sure you have something like this in your settings.py. Particularly, include django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth in your template context processors.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: This also didn't change anything. I believe it should work from the docs, but for some reason it's acting strange. In a moment I'll try my best to add detail to the post

Comment: Added a new block of code. Make sure you have it in your settings.py.

Comment: Yes it was in there automatically. I'll add my middleware classes as well as templates. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the user is authenticated you can access username as

```
{{ request.user.username }}
```

But `settings` must contain

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
  # ...
  'django.core.context_processors.request', #'django.template.context_processors.request', in django1.8
  # ...
)
```

Comment: Nothing has changed, it is still blank, I believe the user is logged in?

Comment: try with `request.user.email` ?

Answer (score 0):

When you passed username and user, you passed a dict.

`{'username': username, 'user':user}`

To access these in HTML, just use `{{username}}` or `{{user}}`